# How do I remove "\n" when export sql result to .txt with bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, newline

I want to export the sql result to .txt with bash my result like this:

```
campaign_id vascode
F190720NBWCA004 Hidden_HVC_Revamp_7_Pre_MT_OP
\n
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_10_Pre_MKIOS_OP
\n
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_10_Pre_MT_OP
\n
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_10_Pre_UMB_OP
\n
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_11_Pre_MKIOS_OP
\n
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_11_Pre_MT_OP
\n
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_11_Pre_UMB_OP
\n
```

I have try with `tr -d '\n' < yourfile.txt` and `sed`, but it's still having "\n" in new line. My code looks like this:

```
workDirectory="/home/data"
tanggal=`date '+%Y%m%d' `

echo "Begin Generating ${tanggal}"

msisdn="SELECT * from database;"

echo "`date '+%T'`  :  Download MSISDN Data.."

/usr/bin/mysql -host -user -pass -database -e"$msisdn" | tr -d '\n'> ${workDirectory}/data/"${tanggal}"_msisdn.txt &

wait

echo "done"
```

This is the result when I use `cat -a`:

```
campaign_id^Ivascode$
F190720NBWCA004^IHidden_HVC_Revamp_7_Pre_MT_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_10_Pre_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_10_Pre_T_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_10_Pre_B_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_11_Pre_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_11_Pre_MT_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_11_Pre_UMB_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_12_Pre_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_12_Pre_UMB_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_13_Pre_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_13_Pre_UMB_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_14_Pre_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_14_Pre_UMB_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_15_Pre_OP^M\n$
F190720NBWCA004^IHVC_Revamp_15_Pre_UMB_OP^M\n$
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
campaign_id vascode
F190720NBWCA004 Hidden_HVC_Revamp_7_Pre_MT_OP
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_10_Pre_MKIOS_OP
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_10_Pre_MT_OP
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_10_Pre_UMB_OP
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_11_Pre_MKIOS_OP
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_11_Pre_MT_OP
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_11_Pre_UMB_OP
```

Can anyone help me achieve my goal?

Comment: Do you mean the `\n` as a newline, or as literally backslash and `n`? If it's the latter, I can't see where it's coming from. If it's the former, in shell you typically need to say `$'\n'` and not `'\n'` for it to be understood (but `tr -d $'\n'` will wipe all newlines, not just some).

Comment: @anubhava must empty , but idk why this file has "\n" in new line, i try another date for sure but its normal

Comment: @amadan every i try conver the result sql to .txt its always "\n" in new line , i want remove it , itry your suggestion ``` tr -d $'\n' ``` but the result same, still has a "\n"in every row

Comment: am i put "tr" in wrong position ?

Comment: @anubhava i try that but its same output campaign_id vascode
F190720NBWCA004 Hidden_HVC_Revamp_7_Pre_MT_OP
\n
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_10_Pre_MKIOS_OP
\n
F190720NBWCA004 HVC_Revamp_10_Pre_MT_OP
\n
F190720NBWCA004 HVC

Comment: ok can you show output of `mysql .... | cat -A` in question

Comment: @anubhava done sir , take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have DOS line ending `\r` and literal `\n` at the end of each line.

You may use:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -host -user -pass -database -e"$msisdn"  | sed $'s/\r\\\\n//'
```

Comment: yea i use dos to edit this  but im already use dos2unix , thanks its work sir , ty very much